# android color menu icons

Tags: android, menu, icons

Is there are a reason why android menu icons are always monochrome and not color?  Is there any reason why i shouldn't use color menu icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design guidelines are laid out here. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

I think it helps maintain consistency among the different apps and devices by different manufacturers. My Samsung Galaxy S's highlight is a blue color so a blue icon would not look good.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the android style guide.  Each different kind of icon has a different style, so that when the user sees an icon of a particular style they know what it means.  See the guidelines for menu icons in the [icon design doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#menustructure).

You don't have to follow the guidelines (unlike Apple, Google won't reject your app if you don't), but its a good idea to do so unless you have a really strong reason why it would be better for your users if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Style. Just the way they decided to do it. I don't see why you couldn't use your own color icons if you think it looks better.

Answer (score 0):

A main reason I see to stick to the guidelines is 
"You will get a good support as the Android version changes."